# how to read file from path in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I want to read files named "ABCbook.txt" under directors A/B/C, which means the path A/B/C depends on the files' name and the folders A/B/C are hierarchical. How can I achieve it in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) to make the file path in a platform-independent way, then open the file using the normal [`with open...`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) technique.

```
import os
my_file = os.path.join('A', 'B', 'C', 'ABCbook.txt')
with open(my_file) as f:
    # your code to work on the file goes here
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

filename = "ABCbook.txt"
path = list(filename[:3]) + [filename]
syspath = os.path.join(*path)

print(syspath)
```

output (on windows):

```
A\B\C\ABCbook.txt
```

on linux or mac it will return

```
A/B/C/ABCbook.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your ans. The path is right however there is another issue pops out though I don't think it has something to do with the path name. It says that  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: though I put the file intended to open and my python file in the same path.

Comment: your python file should be in the top folder, next to A. e.g. project/program.py, project/A/B/C/ABCbook.txt